# How to display images in Muti-Platform Xamarin.Forms Project on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've got a Xamarin.Forms Project containing an Android and an iOS Platform Project.

I've got my whole application working on Android and I am now struggling on the iOS part. I can't get my images to display on iOS.

I've followed the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows) on how to work with images on Xamarin.iOS, but it's simply not working.

I have created a minimum example from a new project and [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/daniel-streetec/Xamarin_ImageTest), it can be found here.

Output: On Android, the image is being displayed fine, on iOS, the screen stays empty. In addition to that, the logs I've added to AppDelegate.cs show, that the images cannot be found by using `UIImage.FromBundle()`

I've also checked the CSProject file of the iOS project, but it already contains the `<ImageAsset>` item groups.

I am on Visual Studio Professional 2022 (Windows) Version 17.4.1

Can someone please have a look into this? I am going crazy...

Comment: the doc you're following is for Xamarin iOS.  For Xamarin Forms, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: Hi @Jason, I know; the guide you linked references the guide i mentioned in its second paragraph (see "Local images")...

Comment: personally, I've always placed iOS images in Resources and that continues to work on the latest versions

Comment: As a test, remove `car_settings_vector` imageset. Close solution, delete that file and its reference in ios csproj, and delete iOS .obj folder to ensure a clean build. It refers to a file named `car_settings.pdf`. While I don't really know, perhaps that `car_settings` is interfering with access to the `car_settings.png` files in the other imageset.

Comment: Hi, I've added that vector file in order to test if the issue is caused by the the image being a vector.
It seems to me, that the toolchain on windows for creating assets for iOS in visual studio is simply broken.
The "solution" of @ToolmakerSteve is working for me, though it contradicts with microsofts documentation and the fact that this type of implementation is officially deprecated

Comment: What's deprecated (but still works) is *individual files* (aaa.png, aaa@x2.png), with no xcasset. An *xcasset* containing those files is not deprecated. Nor is it likely to become deprecated in the future. What is problematic about your setup is that you have TWO different representations of `car_settings`. What happens if you remove the xcasset with .pngs, and rename the one with pdf to match the filename in it? (`car_settings` xcasset, with `car_settings.pdf`).

Answer (score 0):

I have test your project with the Visual Studio 2022 for mac. And I had the same results in the Android platform and ios platform. The small car icon will show at the top of the screen.

But for the iphone 14 pro simulator, which has a notch screen. The car icon almost be covered. So you can try to run it on the ipad or a device without notch screen to check the car icon will show or not.

In addition, I have checked your `Assets.xcassets` folder and the [official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages.iOS/Assets.xcassets) on the github. There is no a such `xxx_vector` folder in it.

Comment: It seems to me, that the toolchain on windows for iOS assets is simply broken. I've tested it on a iPhone SE 2 physical device and it did not display anything. Neither does it on the iPhone 14 Simulator hosted via pair to mac.

Comment: All right, but the image showed when I test it on the ios simulator. It's strange. @DanielS.

Comment: But you tested it on VS for mac, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I forget this. So just delete the `xxx_vector` folder, it will work. Right? @DanielS.

Comment: sadly not... I've updated the Repo if you want to have a look

Comment: When I clone the project to the visual studio on the windows, the Assets.xcassets folder will be ignored. So I tested it on the mac yesterday. @DanielS.

Answer (score 0):

Background information:

- What's deprecated (but still works) is *individual resource files* (aaa.png, aaa@x2.png), with *no xcasset*.
- An *xcasset* containing those files is not deprecated. Nor is it likely to become deprecated in the future.

---

If you still want to test with .pdf containing vectors:

- What is problematic about your setup is that you have TWO representations of `car_settings`. One with .pngs, one with vector pdf.
- What happens if you *remove* the xcasset with `.png`s, and rename the one with pdf to match the filename in it? (`car_settings` xcasset, with `car_settings.pdf`).
- Close VS, and delete all .bin and .obj folders after making this change, to ensure VS correctly rebuilds with the vector version.

If this still fails, then you likely have encountered a bug. Add as an issue at `github xamarin forms issues`. Be sure to mention the versions of VS and Xamarin.Forms that has the problem.